# Typescript React Component type Prop with Generic React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a button component in react. But I am not sure why the `type` Attribute is not recognised as a valid prop. This is what my code looks like right now:

```js
import React, {HTMLAttributes} from 'react';
import {SemanticElementProps} from "../../utils/SemanticElement";

export interface ButtonProps {
  as?: SemanticElementProps['as'];
  spin?: boolean;
}

export type ButtonType<E = HTMLButtonElement> = React.FC<ButtonProps & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>;

export const Button: ButtonType = (
  {
    as,
    type,
    className,
    ...rest
  }
) => {};
```

This is a pattern that I use often. Sometimes, this button component might be a different HTML Element, which is what the `as` prop is for. In that case, I thought I could utilise a generic in order to only add props from attributes that are allowed on a given element.

What am I misunderstanding here?